# Is updating a remote-tracking branch by local branch a good practice?

Tags: git, branching

In [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) you can see:

> Remote-tracking branches are references to the state of remote
>   branches. They’re local references that you can’t move; they’re moved
>   automatically for you whenever you do any network communication ...

So `remote tracking branches` are described as `read only` but it is possible to update, edit and delete a remote tracking branch by a local branch of current repository. For example:

```
$ git push . :refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Which deletes remote tracking branch. But is updating a remote tracking branch by local branch a good practice? If yes, is there another usage of that work?

Comment: Do you mean pushing changes from a local branch to a remote branch?

Comment: @MikePartridge Yes. Is that a good practice or has any logical usage?

Comment: Pushing a local branch to a remote (e.g. origin) is a common practice when the remote is being used as a central repository.

Comment: @MikePartridge Pushing to a repository in central workflow will updates related remote branches after updating `refs` in remote repository. But I mean updating a `remote branch` directly without syncing with remote repository.

Comment: I suspect that using . as the remote invokes the git equivalent of undefined behavior.

Comment: @MikePartridge I edited my question and replaced the term `remote branch` with `remote tracking branch`